# How do you specify Flask 0.11.1 CLI function arguments

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I'm trying out the new Flask 0.11 command line functionality.  I have Flask 0.11.1 and python 2.7.6 installed.  I've managed to define argumentless functions and get them to execute:

```
@myapp.cli.command()
def hi():
    print "hi"

% flask hi
hi
```

How do I specify an argument to the command?  I tried this because of a suggestion from Flask:

```
@myapp.cli.command()
def hi(foo):
   print foo

% flask nowayjose
Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Error: No such command "nowayjose".

% flask hi there
Usage: flask hi [OPTIONS]

Error: Got unexpected extra argument (there)
```

I'm also confused because usage says OPTIONS should be specified after the COMMAND, whereas the first usage says it should be specified before the COMMAND.

I also tried this:

```
@recargo.cli.command()
def hi(foo=None):
    print foo

% flask hi
None
% flask hi --foo 'bar'
Error: no such option: --foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I looked at click and this is the way to specify flag arguments:

```
@myapp.cli.command()
@click.option('--foo', default="woo")
def hi(foo):
    print foo

% flask hi --foo
woo
```

For positional arguments:

```
@myapp.cli.command()
@click.argument('arg')
def hi(arg):
    print arg

% flask hi foobar
foobar
```